# Sd card was partitioned. Need it as 1

Tags: partitioning, formatting, sd-card

I have 64gb sd card. I put an ubuntu os on it. It failed to install. Went to format and overwrite to find it was partitioned. I tried diskmgmt. Tried right clicking on individual drives to delete them. The option doesnt come up for 2 of the partitions. I have also tried sd formatter.
How do i get this sd card to show 1 partition of 64gb like it originally was?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Superuser . Can you add to your question as screenshot of your Disk Management?

Comment: @harrymc, Format would be formatting one partition. He needs something more to manage/delete all the other partitions first

Answer (score 3):

Try cleaning it using `diskpart` and then formatting it.

Open a Command Prompt as Administrator and enter the following commands in order, where the `X` in `select disk X` is the number of the SD card disk obtained from the `list disk` command before that (e.g. `select disk 4`):

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk X
clean
create partition primary
active
format fs=exFat quick
```

(Using ***exFat*** as the filesystem, since that's the default/recommended for SD Cards/Falsh Drives with a capacity greater than 32 GB.)

Comment: *N.B.*: exFAT is a proprietary MS format, and *cannot* be used for drives at bootup, on most PC's, because BIOS cannot read that format. Though FAT32 might be unable to store files larger than ~4 GB, it is still the best option for a boot drive.

Comment: Correct, but it sounds from the question that he doesn't need it for booting anymore (wants to overwrite it), so for regular use that's the typical FS for it. If he's going to need it for boot again, the utility created the bootable USB will already take care of this as well.

Answer (score -1):

To format the disk :

- Run CMD as Administrator
- Enter `diskpart`
- Use these commands :

  - `list disk`
  - `select disk N`
  - `format fs=fat32`

Be very careful to select the right disk !
You may use other formats than FAT32.

Answer (score -1):

It was specific steps.
I guess I was confused on how disk management worked.
I went into disk management, selected my disk(multiple usb drives, i repeated the steps for each one). some of the drives were showing as 3 or 4 separate partitions, and none were booting OS correctly. Some of the partitions could be deleted, some could not. I deleted the ones with the available option through right click. after that i was able to select, create new volume and the majority of the usb was re-partitioned into one. with a new volume created, i was then able to use rufus correctly and all usb drives were functional and the desired OS was written to each drive successfully. I figured out the solution through trial and error, before one was written here, so I did not try any of these solutions offered. I do know it was a problem I encountered years ago, so i feel the solution is relevant for others.